# $lookup using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections like checklists and tasks. Two schemas will look like below

checklist schema will look like beow

```
{
  "_id": "5b7d0f77e231b6b530b0ee5a",
  "audit_checklist_type": "Weekly"

}, {
  "_id": "5b7d3f33e7a57f38084efb09",
  "audit_checklist_type": "Daily"
}
```

Tasks Schema will look like below

```
{
  "_id": "5b7d65daf74be318e8378cf9",
  "checklist_id": "5b7d3f33e7a57f38084efb09"
}, {
  "_id": "5b7d662df74be318e8378cfb",
  "checklist_id": "5b7d3f33e7a57f38084efb09"
}
```

my query is

```
AuditChecklist.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        audit_checklist_type: "Daily"
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'AuditTask',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'checklist_id',
      as: 'TaskData',
    },
  },
]).exec()
```

I'm trying to get the output like

```
{
  "_id": "5b7d3f33e7a57f38084efb09",
  "TaskData ": [{
      "_id": "5b7d65daf74be318e8378cf9",
      "checklist_id": "5b7d3f33e7a57f38084efb09"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b7d662df74be318e8378cfb",
      "checklist_id": "5b7d3f33e7a57f38084efb09"
    }
  ]
}
```

But for me resulting TaskData output is empty.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might getting your data in `auditTaskData` or may be your database name is incorrect....

Comment: Apologies, I edited it. That is **TaskData** only

Comment: what is the type of the `checklist_id` ? are you using mongoose or mongoclient directly?

Comment: I'm storing `checklist_id` as a reference id and i'm using mongoose only

Comment: replace this `from: 'AuditTask'` with  `from: AuditTask.collection.name`... mongoose pluralise the collection name so instead using `AuditTask` you need to use **`audittasks`** or **`AuditTask.collection.name`**

Comment: Actually i'm declaring AuditTask as a variable like below
**var AuditTask = mongoose.model('AuditTask');**

Comment: It doesn't matter... Import or require `AuditTask` just as you have imported `AuditChecklist`  and change your `from` field to `AuditTask.collection.name`...

Comment: Wowww, It worked like champ. Many thanks to you @Anthony Winzlet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mongooose pluralise the database name So instead of using `AuditTask` you should use `audittasks`

**OR**

You can first import the database in your file like:

```
// ESM:
import AuditTask from './AuditTask'
// or CommonJS: 
const AuditTask = require('./AuditTask')
```

and use it in your [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation:

```
{ '$lookup': {
  'from': AuditTask.collection.name,
  'localField': '_id',
  'foreignField': 'checklist_id',
  'as': 'TaskData'
}}
```