# How can I get data referencing form one collection to another? Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

```
router.get('/productSelect', (req, res, next) =>{
    productSchema.aggregate([   
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'supplierSchema',
                localField: 'supplierId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'supplier'
            }
        }

    ], (err, productSchema) =>{
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.json(productSchema);
    });
});
```

I want to get data from collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3",
    "productExist": true,
    "productName": "Anything",
    "supplierId": "5b9d25064dcf2327b449ae1b",
    "brandId": "5b9d162a316e8d2660f26393",
    "categoryId": "5ba2509a6367372568b1ce6d",
    "productPrice": 222,
    "productQuantity": 320,
    "productMax": 3,
    "productMin": 4,
    "productTimeStamp": "2018-09-19T15:49:07.177Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

and replace the supplierId as supplierName from collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5b9d25064dcf2327b449ae1b",
    "supplierExist": true,
    "supplierName": "NBA World Wide",
    "supplierStatus": "Available",
    "supplierTimeStamp": "2018-09-15T15:28:06.971Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the issue in the above code?

Comment: the supplier returns an empty string [{…}]
0
:
brandId
:
"5b9d162a316e8d2660f26393"
categoryId
:
"5ba2509a6367372568b1ce6d"
productExist
:
true
productMax
:
3
productMin
:
4
productName
:
"Anything"
productPrice
:
222
productQuantity
:
320
productTimeStamp
:
"2018-09-19T15:49:07.177Z"
supplier
:
[]
supplierId
:
"5b9d25064dcf2327b449ae1b"
__v
:
0
_id
:
"5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3"

Comment: Might be your collection name is incorrect. Are you using mongoose or mongodb native?

Comment: I am using mongoose. I named the collection of supplier as supplierSchema but when it is in the mongodb compass it is named as supplierSchemas

Comment: Ok then put the same in above code `from: "supplierschemas"`

Comment: from: 'supplierSchemas',
                localField: 'supplierId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'supplier'

it still returns empty supplier[] array

Comment: `S` should be small `supplierschemas` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999445/lookup-using-mongoose/52000908#52000908

Comment: from: 'supplierschemas',
                localField: 'supplierId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'supplier'
still returns an empty array. soryy for the inconvenience

Comment: Could you show your both the schemas

Comment: const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1, 
        maxlength: 50
    },
    supplierId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 24,
        maxlength: 24
    }

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const supplierSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    supplierName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1, 
        maxlength: 50
    },
    supplierStatus: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 20
    }

Comment: Your `supplierId` type is string in product schema that's why it doesn't fetch the data. You need keep it as objectId... btw What is your mongodb version?

Comment: {
                from: 'supplierschemas',
                localField: 'supplierId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'supplier'
            }
i change the type from string to objectId. And it works! :) MongoDB 4.0.2

thank you so much sir! :)

Comment: can I use multiple $lookup? because i am referencing form 3 different collections.

Comment: Yes you can use multiple `$lookup` stages

Comment: it retuns  [ { "_id": "5b9d25064dcf2327b449ae1b", "supplierExist": true, "supplierName": "NBA World Wide", "supplierStatus": "Available", "supplierTimeStamp": "2018-09-15T15:28:06.971Z", "__v": 0 } ]

how can i only get the supplierName? and print it on my html using data binding?

Comment: Hello your above question has been resolved. Please ask a new question if you have further doubts.

Answer (score 2):

For making join with two table you have make sure that the  type for both the fields i.e. `localField` and `foriegnField` should be the same.

**Or**

With mongodb **4.0** you can easily change the type of the `String` to `ObjectId` using [**`$toObjectId`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) aggregation

```
productSchema.aggregate([   
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "supplierSchema",
    "let": { "supplierId": { "$toObjectId": "$supplierId" }},
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$supplierId"] }}}
    ]
    as: "supplier"
  }}
])
```